# html url input disable keyboard autospace after sentence (mobile)

Tags: javascript, html

I have html input fields and in mobile devices, the keyboard automatically adds spaces after sentence.

This is problematic for a input of type "url". How do I disable it?

I tried the following and still adds a space after the period in the domain name.

Comment: _I tried the following_ ????

Comment: Would removing the ability to add a space be sufficient or do you only want to stop the auto-space?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your input stored in a variable and that you are interested in its value only when you do a submit, you can easily trim its value with

```
yourInput.trim();
```

this will remove all leading and trailing spaces, thus cleaning your input.

If you want to delete the spaces directly when typing, you can attach that code to the change event:

```
yourInput.addEventListener('change', e => e.currentTarget.value.trim());
```